# Displaying local time with a UTC datetime input using Date Object

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a form whereby user is required to input a UTC date and a UTC time. The corresponding local date and time will be displayed to the user upon any change in the input fields. The following is the HTML code:

```
<form>
 UTC Date: <input type=text name=cDate value='' size=6 onchange='showLT();'>(DDMMYY)
 <br>
 UTC Time: <input type=text name=cTime value='' size=4 onchange='showLT();'>(HHMM)
 <br>
 Local Date and Time: <span id='local'></span>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function showLT() {
 var A = document.forms[0].cDate.value;
 var B = document.forms[0].cTime.value;
 var C = new Date(A.slice(4,6), A.slice(2,4)-1, A.slice(0,2),
  B.slice(0,2), B.slice(2,4), 0);
 document.getElementById('local').innerHTML = C.toLocaleString();
}
</script>
```

I am facing two problems:

1. For two digits year, I always thought it should be interpreted to
   fall within the range 1970 to 2069. However, when I tried input the
   UTC date as 131211, the year is interpreted to be 1911 and not 2011.
2. The display date shown is *Wed 13 Dec 1911 08:32:00 **MALT***,
   which I presume is the time for Malta, not my locale which is +8 hours away. I have no
   problem displaying my local time in other functions where
   `toLocaleString()` is applied. I am surprise that it shows a
   different time zone in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to specify a four digit year... or add +100 to the current year.

UTC time and POSIX Epoch time are two different things.